# Rewrite jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate to NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have such SQL:

```
private final String SQL_INSERT_OR_UPDATE = "INSERT INTO currency_rate(currency_id, rate, update_date) " +
            "SELECT currency.id, ?, ? " +
            "FROM currency " +
            "WHERE currency.code = ? " +
            "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rate = ?";
```

And code in java:

```
public int[] saveOrUpdate(List<String> codes, List<BigDecimal> rates, LocalDate date) {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
                SQL_INSERT_OR_UPDATE,
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                    public void setValues(@Nonnull PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                        ps.setBigDecimal(1, rates.get(i));
                        ps.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(date));
                        ps.setString(3, codes.get(i));
                        ps.setBigDecimal(4, rates.get(i));
                    }

                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return codes.size();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Now I want to rewrite this code to use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. I know only one way: go thru my lists and create objects. Then put this objects into list and create `SqlParameterSource`. But its allot of objects to be created. Is there another way to use list that I olready have and not create an army of objects?

Comment: Will this work? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/SqlParameterSourceUtils.html#createBatch-java.util.Collection-

Comment: Not really, its just collection of objects which I don`t want to create